# viewWillTransitionToSize stop calling in ios

Tags: ios, orientation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, viewwilltransitiontosize

In one of my application i am using subclass of AVPlayerViewController. In this class i am using viewwillTransistion method to adjust view width and height after rotate device. But i am seeing strange behaviour that is if keep on changing the orientation from potrait to landscape and landscape to potrait after few attempts like this this method itself not triggering / stop calling.

Even after dismiss this view also remaining screens also not changing orientation i means viewwillTransistion is not triggering in other classes as well so finally total orientaion change support is gone.

May i know i need to do to fix this issue and what is the issue why its happening.